# Как правильно объединить .hover() & .animate()?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Не могу понять, как отменить множественный `hover`, и чтобы срабатывал только последний. Когда я очень быстро мышкой навожу на блок, анимация отрабатывает столько, сколько раз я навел, даже если мышка уже не на блоке. Можно это как то убрать? Или это особенность `jquery`?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    var headerSearch = $('.header__search');

    headerSearch.mouseenter(function () {
        $('.header__search-input').stop().animate({
           width : '100%',
           opacity: 1
        },'slow');
        $('.header__search').animate({
            'max-width' : '100%'
        },'fast');
    });
      
    headerSearch.mouseleave(function () {
        $('.header__search-input').stop().animate({
            width : 0,
            opacity: 0
        },'slow');
        $('.header__search').animate({
            'max-width' : '70%'
        },'fast');
    });
    
});
```

```css
.header__search {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    top: 93px;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 70%;
    width: 100%;
}

.header__search-input{
    float: right;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}

.header__search-btn {
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="header__search" method="get" action="#">
  <input class="header__search-input" type="search" placeholder="Поиск..." style="width: 0px; opacity: 0;">
            <div class="header__search-btn">
              <button type="submit"><span class="fa fa-search">Search</span></button>
            </div>
          </form>
```

Comment: Работает вполне нормально. Только еще для анимации `header__search` вызов `stop` добавьте и вообще замечательно будет.

Answer (score 0):

Еще `stop` надо добавить к анимации `header__search`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var headerSearch = $('.header__search');

  headerSearch.mouseenter(function() {
    $('.header__search-input').stop().animate({
      width: '100%',
      opacity: 1
    }, 'slow');
    $('.header__search').stop().animate({
      'max-width': '100%'
    }, 'fast');
  });

  headerSearch.mouseleave(function() {
    $('.header__search-input').stop().animate({
      width: 0,
      opacity: 0
    }, 'slow');
    $('.header__search').stop().animate({
      'max-width': '70%'
    }, 'fast');
  });

});
```

```css
.header__search {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  top: 93px;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 70%;
  width: 100%;
}

.header__search-input {
  float: right;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

.header__search-btn {
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="header__search" method="get" action="#">
  <input class="header__search-input" type="search" placeholder="Поиск..." style="width: 0px; opacity: 0;">
  <div class="header__search-btn">
    <button type="submit"><span class="fa fa-search">Search</span></button>
  </div>
</form>
```